# Recursive function failing with "This method must return a result of type int"

Tags: java

This code is supposed to do `x/y`, but for some reason, it says:

> This method must return a result of type int

Can you help me fix it?

```
public class Recursion2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(func3(4, 2));
        
    }//main

    public static int func3(int x, int y)
    {
    if(x == y) return 1;
    if(x - y < x) return 1 + func3(x - y, y);
    } 
}//class
```

Comment: You don't return anything if neither of your conditions is true.

Comment: What if neither `x == y` nor `x - y < x` return true?

Comment: "`if(x - y < x)`" is (roughly) the same as `if (y > 0)`.

Comment: just as an exercise,  what should I write different to make it work?

Comment: There are many cases uncovered with this code, what about negative values ? Also your recursion is not returning correct values in all cases. Search for algorithm online i am sure your will find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if(x - y < x) return 1 + func3(x - y, y);
```

To:

```
if((x - y) < x) return 1 + func3(x - y, y);
```

Addition:

Maybe the problem causes because not every time a result is returned. In Java you have to return a result always. So you have to add else-cases or a default case. This would fix the issue I think.